# iphone - web service communication for mac => Required packet sniffing assitance

Tags: iphone, http-headers

I would like to see the HTTP request and response headers sent and received in my MAC. Is there any tool which can sniff the wireless data too. Kindly help. Wireshark didnt work out well for me as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [HttpScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/)?

It works well and it's not so complex as WireShark. Anyway if you manage to get WireShark running you won't need any other tool :-)

Comment: Actually the problem is im unable to configure. As you said if that is done then no problem at all. Anyways HTTPScoop seems to be a nice tool to work. Thanks a lot mate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Charles proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is the standard where I work, and it does an excellent job of capturing packets coming into and out of your mac.

Comment: Surprisingly my network firewall blocked this site.. i will try @home.anyways its a great help.. Thanks a lot mate